How do i send images captured on my pi 4 through LAN to my pc?
I currently have a raspberry pi 4 set up as a astrophotography rig, i capture the images directly to an external storage device to protect the internal storage and to avoid any possible performance losses due to the accumulation of images.
All of this is run by an app i made, but i was hoping to add a selector to help me choose if i want to send the images through the LAN instead or maybe save to both at the same time.
The thing is that i dont really know much about managing networks or FTP or any sort of protocol, so i could use a hand with figuring out what it is that i need to learn here.
Summary:
How do i save images taken on rpi, directly to a LAN device like a pc, home server, etc?

run a web server on the RPi ... couple of lines of python code would do it
